# How to replace web.config with transformed for debug file when running WAP in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config, visual-studio-debugging

I want to replace web.config with transformed for debug config file when running in Visual Studio( I am NOT interesting in publishing project to some output directory). I want to keep original web.config in the root of web application in TFS, but on runtime (on IIS or Cassini) I want to use transformed debug version.

The best approach that I found so far (in [Use Visual Studio web.config transform for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922291/use-visual-studio-web-config-transform-for-debugging)  and [ASP.NET Web Projects: web.debug.config & web.release.config](http://sedodream.com/2010/10/21/ASPNETWebProjectsWebdebugconfigWebreleaseconfig.aspx) ) is to use web.template.config as a master file, and web.config as derived transformed file.
I am not fully happy with it, because developers use to consider web.config  as a master file.

I have an idea to output transformed file to ASP.Net temporary files directory, that ASP.NET used for cached files.

Does ASP.NET use web.config file from temporary cache folfder?
Will ASP.NET allow to have web.config file in cache directory different to web.config  in original folder?

I found a couple properties, related to ASP.Net temporary files directory.
MSBuild [tempDirectory property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.compilationsection.tempdirectory.aspx) of the CompilationSection can be used to replace root folder  of ASP.Net temporary files.
[ClientBuildManager.CodeGenDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.clientbuildmanager.codegendir%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Property gives access to specific folder where current cache is located.

However I could not find, how to access path of the folder from MSBuild and will it allow me to output transformed web.config to cached folder.

Any suggestions/considerations will be appreciated.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922291/use-visual-studio-web-config-transform-for-debugging ?

Comment: I've explain in the question, why web.template.config solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922291/use-visual-studio-web-config-transform-for-debugging is not ideal and my question asking is it possible to use asp.net temporary folder.

Answer (score 0):

The debug and release templates of the config file are used when you deploy the application.  Can you use the publish option to publish the application to another virtual directory on your machine for debugging purposes?  Then, you would have the transformed config file.

Comment: I've added a clarification to my question, that I am NOT interesting in publishing project to some output directory. I just want to run and debug.