# Generate Web.Debug.config which could be debugged

Tags: c#, azure-web-roles, webrole

I have a web role
Its web.config has a following lines

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

When I want to debug my role each time I need to switch that option to `true`.
Can I generate only for debug web.config with `debug="true"?`
While compiling I have see the transforming step:

```
Transformed Web.config using C:\data\Main\WebRole\Web.Debug.config into C:\data\Main\obj\x64\Debug\WebRole.csproj\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
```

Can I customize the above transformation?
There is a guidance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx for that purpose but I am not sure how to write a transformation for specific case

I`ve defined the following transformation in the`Web.Debug.Config`

```
<system.web>
      <compilation debug="true"
        xdt:Transform="Replace">
      </compilation>
</system.web>
```

I still can`t debug and asked to change the value manually

Comment: When you want to debug, you have to set it to `true`, not `false`

Comment: yes - sure that what I meant. was typo - fixed

Comment: You should try your solution an tell us if it's ok or not. And if it's not OK, what is the current result ?

Answer (score -1):

The web.debug.config is not used when you are running/debugging from sources : [Use Visual Studio web.config transform for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922291/use-visual-studio-web-config-transform-for-debugging)

It easier to set `debug="true"` in `Web.config` and remove it using `Web.release.config`.

Sample Web.Release.Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I need to make my changes in debug