# ApplicationInsights TelemetryClient is very slow at initializing when in Debug

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have a problem with `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` objects. Every time the code hits one of those objects for the first time, the time to initialize is ridiculously long (sometimes even around 40 seconds).

Example 1:

[image: First initialization of TelemetryClient]

Example 2:

[image: DisableTelemtry]

What is the cause of this long first time load? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just disable ApplicationInsight when in debug using a web.config transform?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
      <httpModules>
        <add xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"  />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I had similar issues and the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922291/use-visual-studio-web-config-transform-for-debugging) explained to me how to go about using this snippet in my dev environment (ie. not in the publishing pipeline).

Comment: Thanks, I've just disabled it - my app starts a lot faster.

Comment: I doubt that during a normal debug session the transform is triggered?!

Comment: @FalcoAlexander - try... it does.

Comment: I tried, it still fires Insight events. even though I had to add:  `<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule"  />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>`

Comment: also had to add `<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
    <listeners>
        <add xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="myAppInsightsListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>`...now it's quiet :)  @LeonardoSeccia what about adding that to you answer?