# Are web.config transformations applied when I "Start Debugging" in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use Web.debug.config in the built-in visual studio debugger server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305096/how-can-i-use-web-debug-config-in-the-built-in-visual-studio-debugger-server)

I added a Debug/Release web.config transformation file to a web application project.

While its working when I build a deployment package it is not applied when I simply "start debugging" (green play button). Is this the expected behaviour or should the transformations be applied? What are best practices to switch between different configurations in development?

How can I raplidly test if a web.config transformation works and whats the resulting web.config file?

Comment: For a way to get this behavior, see here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3994081/1092630

Answer (score 2):

No; only when you build the deployment package - and they are not applied to the files in your project at all - so they are not present from the project, debugging or otherwise - without some custom step to get the transformed `web.config` moved.

Comment: Thx. Any suggestions for the related questions above? How to simulate/test and best practices for development?