# C# General Question about AppSetting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to pull a value from my Web.Debug.Config file most specifically from the AppSettings, it's just a string "Here are the books". But I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object. What do I need to fix, I am just trying to pass this to a Text Box

```
     string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mybooks"];
        TextBoxq.Text = s;
```

Thank you

Web.Debug.config app settings:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="mybooks" value="my test label value"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that calling ToString on a string isn't useful :)

Comment: hehe ok ty, i was just trying everything lol

Comment: Does it work with the web.config (w/o the 'debug.')?

Comment: Post the `<appsettings>` section from you Web.config file.

Comment: Can you show us the app setting in Web.Debug.Config?

Comment: I dont know I only have to types of WebConfig.. i dont see the traditional WebConfig file, it just placed two Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config .... this in VS2010.. This is new to me too

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="mybooks" value="my test label value"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely problem is that you aren't using "WebDeploy" which means that the .Debug version of your config file is ignored.  If that's the case, put the setting in Web.Config directly and try again.  If that's not the case, post the relevant pieces of your config file so we can help.

Comment: <appSettings> <add key="mybooks" value="my test label value"/> </appSettings>

Answer (score 0):

The files are not combined until published. Are you trying to read it while debugging?

See [ASP.NET MVC3: Debug and Release app settings not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209125/asp-net-mvc3-debug-and-release-app-settings-not-wokring)

Answer (score 0):

Web applications looks specifically for a file called Web.config. Try renaming your 'Web.debug.config' to just 'Web.config'.

Comment: I was actually mitaken , I was confused by those two Web Config files but I see that the WebConfig (root of both) contains the actual WebConfig file. I added the   <appSettings>
    <add key="mybooks" value="my test label value"/>
  </appSettings> but still no luck