# Custom error page in "Release" mode and default error page in "Debug" mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I want to show a custom error page when the project is in production (release mode) and show the default error page from asp.net when running the page in (debug mode).

I have three Web.config files in my project.

- Web.config
- Web.Debug.config
- Web.Release.config

This is what I have tried but had no luck.

**Web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/Error" />
</customErrors>
```

**Web.Debug.config**

```
<customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="Replace"></customErrors>
```

**Web.Release.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/Error" />
</customErrors>
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**
After reading around, I'm thinking that this is a known bug but I wasn't able to find a bug fix for this. If anyone knows more about this, please share. Thanks

Comment: If your on vs2010 install the free slowcheeta extension. It gives each transformation xml file a right click -> Preview function that is very useful debugging these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay. So I figured out what was wrong.

**Web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error.htm"></customErrors>
```

**Web.Debug.config**

```
<compile debug="true" />
<customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="Replace"></customErrors>
```

**Web.Release.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.htm" xdt:Transform="Replace">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

The changes above will keep error messages disabled by default and whenever the project is deployed on the production server, the settings in `Web.Release.config` will overwrite the default `Web.config`

Here is a list of resources / links that I found helpful:

- [Use Visual Studio web.config transform for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922291/use-visual-studio-web-config-transform-for-debugging)
- http://sedodream.com/2010/10/21/ASPNETWebProjectsWebdebugconfigWebreleaseconfig.aspx

I hope this helps anyone else that is trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I think you should update your links, the first one has a death link (literally).

Answer (score 1):

This is a know bug. That feature can be used right now only as part of the deploy process.
Please check this below post

[How can I use Web.debug.config in the built-in visual studio debugger server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305096/how-can-i-use-web-debug-config-in-the-built-in-visual-studio-debugger-server)

or you could just use the 'default' web.config as your development/debugging version, and then the web.release.config would of course continue to be the release version, since its transforms are applied when you publish.

Hope it will help.

Comment: So any changes made in Web.Release.config will only be executed when the project is deployed on the server?

Comment: @FarhanAhmad Yes, that's what this feature does.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out what was wrong. See my answer.